# How to create an overlay on click of a button?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a problem creating an overlay on click of a button, and re-clicking it will close the overlay.

```html
<section>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <section class="masthead">           
      <span class="button">This is a button</span>            
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `<div>` with fixed position for your overlay. Add an onClickListener for your `<span class="button">` that calls your `toggleOverlay()` function. And change the `opacity` of your overlay `<div>` to hide/show it. Code example below:

```js
function toggleOverlay() {
  let overlayDiv = document.querySelector(".overlay");
  console.log(overlayDiv.style.opacity);
  if (overlayDiv.style.opacity === '0')
    overlayDiv.style.opacity = 1;
  else
    overlayDiv.style.opacity = 0;
}
```

```css
.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 30px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay" style="opacity: 0;">Overlay</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div>
  <button onclick="toggleOverlay()">Show/Hide Overlay</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried this one and works on a rails app but the js doesn't work on a simple HTML file where I edited on sublime text, and i wanted to see the changes of the file on chrome as well, any solutions on that?

Comment: Add the JavaScript inside a `<script>`.

Answer (score 0):

A solution for the problem:

Javascript:

```
function init() {
  var btn = document.getElementById("overlayBtn");
  var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
  btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    addOverlay();
  });
  overlay.addEventListener("click", function() {
    removeOverlay();
  });
}

function addOverlay() {
  var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
  overlay.style.display = "block";
}

function removeOverlay() {
  var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
  overlay.style.display = "none";
}

window.onload = init;
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <main class="main">
      <section class="masthead">
        <button id="overlayBtn" class="button">This is a button</button>
      </section>
      <div class="overlay" id="overlay"></div>
    </main>
  </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
  height: 100vh;
}

.overlay {
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.2;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

Could be a start of creating an overlay. But there are many ways to do this. This is using a fixed div occupying the entire screen. Only showing it when it is toggled, and on click on the overlay will make it disappear again.

Working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/eG8fkhvMYnzAQP0SRPSc?p=preview